# window function rolling sum

Tags: sql

I have a window function that gives me a rolling sum as below:

```
    SELECT start_terminal,
       duration_seconds,
       start_time,
       sum(duration_seconds) OVER
         (PARTITION BY start_terminal order by start_time)
         AS running_total
  FROM tutorial.dc_bikeshare_q1_2012
 WHERE start_time < '2012-01-08'
```

but when some timestamps in the start_time column are equal the rolling sum stays the same, which makes sense bc I am ordering by start time, but it does not properly add the duration_seconds in the rolling sum as below: how can i fix or account for this?

```
current output:
     start_terminal duration_seconds start_time         running_total
        31000          74              2012-01-01 15:32:00     74
        31000          291             2012-01-02 12:40:00     365
        31000          520             2012-01-02 19:15:00     885
        31000          424             2012-01-03 07:22:00     1756
        31000          447             2012-01-03 07:22:00     1756
        31000         1422             2012-01-03 12:32:00     3178
         31000         348             2012-01-04 17:36:00     3526
```

desired:

```
start_terminal duration_seconds start_time         running_total
            31000          74              2012-01-01 15:32:00     74
            31000          291             2012-01-02 12:40:00     365
            31000          520             2012-01-02 19:15:00     885
            31000          424             2012-01-03 07:22:00     1756
            31000          447             2012-01-03 07:22:00     2203
            31000         1422             2012-01-03 12:32:00     3625
             31000         348             2012-01-04 17:36:00     3973
```

Comment: What results do you want?  The results look correct to me.

Comment: I just want the running_total to keep adding the duration_seconds even if the start_time is the same because in my current query and output, it doesnt add the 447 amount bc the start time is equal to the prior row so. it does not give me the correct running total

Comment: added desired output thanks for looking @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the `duration_seconds` column to the `order by` in the `partition`, that should give you what you're looking for.

```
    SELECT start_terminal,
       duration_seconds,
       start_time,
       sum(duration_seconds) OVER
         (PARTITION BY start_terminal order by start_time, duration_seconds)
         AS running_total
  FROM tutorial.dc_bikeshare_q1_2012
 WHERE start_time < '2012-01-08'
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear how you want to resolve the tie.  But the default window frame for `order by` is `range between`.  You seem to want `rows between`:

```
SELECT start_terminal, duration_seconds, start_time,
       sum(duration_seconds) OVER (
           partition by start_terminal
           order by start_time
           rows between unbounded preceding and current row
          ) as running_total
FROM tutorial.dc_bikeshare_q1_2012
WHERE start_time < '2012-01-08';
```

If you want a secondary key on `duration_seconds`, you can add that to the `order by`.  However, you'll have the same issue if two rows have the same values for both columns.  If you had an id column or created at, then that could be used as a tie-breaker.